# How do I draw android.graphics.drawable.Icon on canvas?

Tags: android, icons, android-canvas

I'm startled.
I was sure Icon will behave an any other drawable. But I don't see any draw or setBounds methods. I can't find any examples of outputting Icon(lot of them for creating one from bitmap). How do I draw something I have as  android.graphics.drawable.Icon on canvas in specific place?

Comment: Use `loadDrawable()` to get a `Drawable` representing the `Icon`, then render the `Drawable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `loadDrawable(Context context)` method to get a `Drawable` object as mentioned in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html#loadDrawable(android.content.Context))

> Returns a Drawable that can be used to draw the image inside this Icon, constructing it if necessary. Depending on the type of image, this may not be something you want to do on the UI thread, so consider using loadDrawableAsync instead.

**Context:** Context in which to load the drawable; used to access Resources, for example.

**Returns :** A fresh instance of a `drawable` for this image, yours to keep.